# Cambiar el valor de grid-template-columns con js

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, grid

```js
let numSquares = 6
let colors = generateRandomColors(6)
let squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square")
let pickedColor = pickColor()
let colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay")
let message = document.querySelector("#message")
let h1 = document.querySelector("h1")
let buttonReset = document.querySelector("#reset")
let easyButton = document.querySelector("#easyBtn")
let hardButton = document.querySelector("#hardBtn")
// colorDisplay.style.background = pickedColor;

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].style.background = colors[i]
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    let clickedColor = this.style.background
    if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
      message.textContent = "Correct! "
      buttonReset.textContent = "Play Again! "
      changeColors(clickedColor)
      // h1.style.background = clickedColor
    } else {
      this.style.background = "#000000"
      message.textContent = "Try Again! "
    }
  })
}
//todos los cuadrados se cambiarán al color ganador
function changeColors(color) {
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].style.background = color;
  }
}
//genera un número aleatorio 
function pickColor() {
  let colorRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
  return colors[colorRandom]
}
//generador de colores aleatorio por cada primaire
function randomColor() {
  let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
  let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
  let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
  return "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")"
}
//creacion de arreglo de randomColors
function generateRandomColors(number) {
  let arrayNewColors = []
  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    arrayNewColors[i] = randomColor()
  }
  return arrayNewColors
}
//Reseteo combinado funciones con el boton reste
function resetFunction() {
  colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares)
  pickedColor = pickColor()
  colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    if (colors[i]) {
      squares[i].style.background = colors[i]
      squares[i].style.display = "block"
    } else {
      squares[i].style.display = "none"
    }
  }
  buttonReset.textContent = "New Colors"
}

buttonReset.addEventListener("click", function () {
    resetFunction()
})

easyButton.addEventListener("click", easyGame)

let container = document.querySelector("#container")
function easyGame() {
  hardButton.classList.remove("selected");
  easyButton.classList.add("selected");
  container.style.GridTemplateColumns = "1fr 1fr 1fr"
  numSquares = 3;
}

easyButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    resetFunction()
})
hardButton.addEventListener("click", hardGame)

function hardGame() {
  hardButton.classList.add("selected");
  easyButton.classList.remove("selected");
  numSquares = 6;
}
hardButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  resetFunction()
})
```

```css
/* fonts */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Kodchasan";
  src: url(../fonts/Kodchasan-Regular.ttf);
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Arvo";
  src: url(../fonts/Arvo-Regular.ttf);
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
:root {
  scrollbar-width: none !important;
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
/* fonts */

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: "Arvo";
  margin: 0;
}
/* titulo */
#tittle {
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, #0cc90c, blue); */
  background-image: url(./images/rgbgradient-1.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 120%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
    font-size: 40px;
  width: 100vw;
}
#colorDisplay {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-style: italic;
}
/* #colorDisplay::first-letter{
  color: red;
} */

/* titulo */

/* container */
#message {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 50px;
  /* background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)  ; */
}
.message_p{
  display: block;
}
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.square {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  background-color: rgb(89, 0, 255);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
/* container */

/* stripe */
.selected {
  padding: 10px;
}
#easyBtn {
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.753) 80%,
    rgb(255, 102, 0)
  );
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

}
#hardBtn {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgb(255, 102, 0)80%,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.753) 
  );
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

}
button {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: inherit;
  outline: none;
}
#stripe {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#reset {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
}
#stripe button {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* stripe */

/* foter */
/* FOOTER */
footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 110px;
}


/*  */


#footer_copy {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Kodchasan";
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Color Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./responsive.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
    <section id="tittle">
        <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay"></span> Guessing Game</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="stripe">
        <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
        <button class="selected" id="easyBtn">Easy</button>
        <button class="selected" id="hardBtn">Hard</button>


        <p class="message_p"> <span id="message"></span></p>
    </section>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>

    <footer id="footer">
        <h4 id="footer_copy">  <a href=" https://victoriarodriguez-portfolio.netlify.app/"> 2021 &copy; Victoria Rodriguez </a></h4>
    </footer>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

> Hola, quisiera saber si a alguien mas le pasa lo siguiente. Este proyecto corre y funciona en chrome, pero no en firefox. y aca tampoco corre, a que se debe? que tengo que hacer para que funcione en cualquier lado?
> El error concreto, es que nunca hay un color correcto cuando lo ejecuto en firefox, nunca coincide ni se muestra el mensaje de correcto. Pero en chrome si funciona, los colores si coinciden.
> Queria que cuando se ejecuta la funcion easyGame, las columnas sean 3, y no 2, como podria hacer eso desde js?
> Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola , por favor añade tu codigo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: lo habia agregado, pero se ve que o borré. perdon, no manejo bien stack

Comment: que mensaje te da la consola? @VictoriaRodriguez